# Anchor custom UIView to bottom of screen relative to screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, autolayout

I'm currently attempting to create a custom pull-up menu for the iPhone that I can simply hook up to any amount of view controllers in the Storyboard Editor, my code works as intended in terms of animation/IBActions etc however I can't seem to anchor the view as I wish for the iPhone 4-inch Form Factor (iPhone 5 and above).

I've tried various constraints but I just can't seem to get the view to stick. I've removed all constraints out of sheer frustration at this point so the two views are simply existing by themselves for the time being.

The screenshots below show my issue:

iPhone 4/4S view:

[image]

iPhone 5/5C/5S view:

[image]

As you can see, the highlighted view in the iPhone 5 view shows what should be hidden off screen. The idea solution I'm hoping for will ideally be some sort of configuration using Autolayout I've not considered or at worst adding some more code to position the UIView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use Autolayout to do this. To start, select the view and you're trying to pin the bottom of the screen, and select the Autolayout "Pin" button, the 3rd button from the left in the cluster of buttons in the bottom right of your screenshot. You should see this menu.

The values may be different depending on the screen size you're using, and the size of the view you're trying to constrain, but you'll want to first select the drop down menu for the top constraint. You'll want to make sure that you select the bottom option to constrain to the "Top Layout Guide". After you add this constraint to your view, you'll want to expand your constraints on the Interface Builder "Document Outline" (the left bar). Select the "Vertical Space" constraint and navigate to the "Attributes Inspector" (4th icon on the right bar). Change the "Relation" drop down from "Equal" to "Less Than or Equal".

[image]

Then you'll need to do something similar for the bottom constraint, except this time, you'll want to select the second to bottom option "View" (current distance = 0)

[image]

Then set constraints for the sides as needed. You may want to just use the same constraint type as you did for the bottom edge, assuming of course that the bar will always be 320pts wide and centered horizontally on screen.

Comment: It works as I wanted it to on both size devices which is great, but now I have a warning saying that my view has an ambiguous layout. Can I just ignore this and carry on in bliss or is this something I should try to resolve?

Comment: @DarrylBayliss You should be able to solve that by adding both left and right side constraints of some kind. And if this solves the problem, please don't forget to mark as correct :)